# j_spring_security_check returns 404 on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

Login works fine in dev/local environment using Jetty, however, when deployed to Tomcat the login action (j_spring_security_check) return 404. No exception in the log files so I am puzzled with this.

Is there a special Tomcat setup that I am missing?

Comment: What's the context URL when deployed into Jetty? Do you perhaps need to use a JSTL tag for that `action`? (Could you just use Spring Boot and avoid the issue entirely?)

Comment: I tried using the JSTL (`<c:url` ) but to no avail. Can't use Spring boot (shared code). I don't think I fully understand your first question though? Context is the same for both (/motor). So when submitting the page it Posts to` //server:port/motor/j_spring_security_check`.  Thanks.